# Внешний ключ (FOREIGN KEY)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пытаюсь настроить внешний ключ (FOREIGN KEY).
Нужно, чтобы при удалении строки в таблице evpl_orders, удалялась строка в таблице evpl_orders_places, в обоих таблицах есть столбец "order_id". Через него и нужно сделать связи.
Делаю такой запрос:

```
ALTER TABLE evpl_orders_places
ADD CONSTRAINT evpl_orders FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
   REFERENCES evpl_orders (order_id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Не помогает. Ошибок тоже никаких нет.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1480bf31dec6439d97a46a7265a4fe03

Comment: Движок таблицы какой?

Comment: используется таблица mysql

Comment: `в обоих таблицах есть столбец "evpl_orders_id"` а связь настраивается по `order_id`

Comment: MySQL - это СУБД. Я спрашиваю какой движок у конкретных таблиц?

Comment: Покажите полный вывод `SHOW CREATE TABLE evpl_orders_places;`

Comment: [Раз](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engines.html), [Два](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-foreign-key)

Comment: Добавил скриншот в тему.

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? Нужен **весь** вывод запроса, а не первые две строчки

Comment: Это и есть весь вывод, больше ничего нет.

Comment: Станьте на ячейку `Create Table` и нажмите `Ctrl-C`. А потом результат вставьте сюда

Comment: Был отключен полный

Comment: показ, вот полностью:

Comment: CREATE TABLE `wp_12ae_evpl_orders_places` (
 `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
 `event_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
 `event_places` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
 `event_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
 KEY `event_id` (`event_id`),
 KEY `event_date` (`event_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8068 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

Comment: Вообще никаких вариантов решения нет?